# Ping or accessing WAN IP from LAN results in failure on only one box

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, lan

Morning/evening gents.

I purchased a radical domain name today to set up a name for my services and to set up SSL. I configured the SSL fine and all but when I went to my website I couldn't connect. I can connect to the site with any other device in my house and my friend can connect to it as well from outside of the LAN. I am hosting the services with my computer and I can't access the service. Whenever I ping it using the command prompt I get a result of "General Failure.". It saddens me that they couldn't make a better message as it kind of brings me down. I'm not sure what's the deal here as I have all of my firewalls down and my ports are forwarded. Running Windows 7.

Thanks for the assistance chaps.

Comment: I don't think this is related to SSL, so you might want to untag it.  Also you might want to tag it with an OS.  My guess is the problem you are seeing is a driver failure on a Windows box.

Comment: By driver failure I mean driver failure for the network adaptor.

Comment: So, everyone can connect to site but you? Are you trying to connect from the same machine? Maybe modify the hosts file?

Answer (score 0):

Several NAT boxes ("DSL/cable routers") send all traffic from the inside which does not have a destination address in the local private network upstream to the ISP, even when it is addressed at the NAT boxes' external address.

Several ISPs treat traffic coming from a user's IP address which is destined back at the same IP address as an error and will drop it and maybe even send back an ICMP error message.

Together, this means that the machine can be reached fine from the outside, but not from the inside. Your options are to convince your ISP to change its policy or upgrade your NAT box (sometimes a software upgrade helps).

Talking to your ISP is pretty hopeless and would still cause the traffic to round-trip to the ISP, thereby making a (theoretically) local connection slow.

Comment: Is there an option or something that I am looking for when I upgrade my NAT box?

Comment: Hmm, it is generally not a tickmark on the box. I know that a few years ago, Fritz!Boxes had that problem and newer models no longer do. Are you running NAT? What happens if you `telnet` from a box behind to a forwarded port on the public address?

Comment: I think I am on a NAT. Other nodes behind the NAT can connect to the WAN IP and successfully access my services. I wasn't sure how to telnet to a forwarded port so I just opened CMD and typed "telnet myip port". It returned nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by "returned nothing"? Did you immediately get another prompt, an error message, or "connected" and then nothing more?

Comment: After using that command it returned nothing. The screen was blank. No error message or no "connected".